# Running a TCP server in an Android app

Tags: android

As a proof of concepts, I'm implementing an Android app that runs a very simple TCP server in the background to handle connections from certain IoT devices. I also have to communicate with the server from certain activities to send some data back to the IoT devices.
What should I use to run the server in the background? There are AsyncTasks, threads, and Android services. What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to only listen on the TCP port while some activity of yours is in the foreground, have that activity simply fork a thread.

If your objective is to have your app listen on the TCP port while your UI is in the background, use a service that forks a thread.

`AsyncTask` and `IntentService` are fine for transactional work (disk I/O, Web service calls, etc.) but are not well-suited for indefinite use.

Also, bear in mind that having an open port raises security issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My objective is to only listen on the TCP port while my activity is in the foreground. So the best would be to create the server task in a separate thread? But how would I communicate with it?

Comment: @Javiator: Communicate with what? Other than needing to worry about the `INTERNET` permission, and needing to worry about mobile devices being mobile (and hence switching between networks), there is nothing about implementing sockets on Android that is any different than implementing sockets on traditional Java. And Java programs have been working with the Internet for the better part of two decades. Find a library that works on Android and meets your particular needs.

Comment: I have to listen to messages continuously from all activities, Is it ok to run the TCP server in the service?

Comment: @AarthTandel: You would not need a service in that case. Quoting my answer, with emphasis added: "If your objective is to have your app listen on the TCP port **while your UI is in the background**, use a service that forks a thread."